# Django form validation in views

Tags: django, validation, forms

I was wondering if it was possible to do form validation in django views. I have usecases where I have one view with 2 forms. Each forms has their own clean method and such, but what i can't do at the form level is to check if one value is present in the one form, do something else in the other form.

This is simple to check in a view, but I cant find a way to update the non_field_errors() list and raise a ValidationError in a view. I can of course raise a ValidationError in a view, but that doesn't return back to the form and display the error.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Pass the first form to second form's `__init__` and check in clean or clean_xxx methods whatever you wish to check.

Comment: Yeah, I've thought about that and it should work, but doesn't seem very clean. Then I have to decide before I know the results which form that should raise the ValidationError. And the form gets coupled to the other.

Comment: but when forms are already related you can not avoid coupling, you are just trying to move validation code from form to outside form which IMO is more unclean

Comment: They are not necessarily related, but in this one use case they are, but the forms can be used unrelated other places.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of a late answer, but you can use

```
form.add_error(<field>, <errormsg>)
```

to invalidate a form field from a view function.